# docker the docker registry (a private installation of it) use https (tls/ssl)

Tags: docker

When you run your own registry (as per http://blog.docker.io/2013/07/how-to-use-your-own-registry/) there is a pattern to follow with tagging your image/repository so when you push - it goes to your private repo.

There is no space for a protocol - how is this secured - TLS or ssh? it also runs on http but there doesn't seem to be a way to explicitly specify to only use https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It pings the private registry to see if https is available first, and if not it will use http. So, if you offer a https version of your private repo, it will automatically use it.

You can see the code in Docker where this happens here.

https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/master/registry/registry.go#L116

Comment: You can also block HTTP traffic from your private install, so in case docker falls back to http in case of error, it won't work.

Comment: Thanks guys. I don't like this design decision, but glad it works. (reasoning: there is a time to implicit vs explicit, but picking secured vs non secured protocols is probably not one of those times, however). But as long as it can be restricted - all good!